# How can I remove all imported modules in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, module

I wan to remove all imported modules before importing them so that I can get the fresh ones by overwriting the ones in the memory.

How can I remove all imported modules in PowerShell?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this  should do it:

```
get-module | Remove-Module
```

this remove also imported modules in `$profile`.

[More about this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff642467.aspx)